# Distribute elements of one list over elements of another list

Tags: kdb

I have two lists:

```
l1:`a`b`c;
l2: til 20;
```

I am trying to create a dictionary 'd' that contains the elements of 'l1' as key and the elements of 'l2' evenly distributed over it. So like this:

```
d:(`a`b`c)!(0j, 3j, 6j, 9j, 12j, 15j, 18j;1j, 4j, 7j, 10j, 13j, 16j, 19j;2j, 5j, 8j, 11j, 14j, 17j)
```

The order of the elements is not relevant, I just need them balanced. I was able to achieve that in an iterative way (happy to add the code, if that's considered helpful), but there must be a more elegant way (potentially with adverbs?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done using the `group` :

```
q)group (count[l2]#l1)
(`a`b`c)!(0j, 3j, 6j, 9j, 12j, 15j, 18j;1j, 4j, 7j, 10j, 13j, 16j, 19j;2j, 5j, 8j, 11j, 14j, 17j)
```

If your `l2` is something else instead of `til 20` , then you have to lookup the items back after grouping :

```
q)l2: 20#.Q.a
q)l2
"abcdefghijklmnopqrst"
q)l2 group (count[l2]#l1)     // lookup the items back from l2 after grouping 
(`a`b`c)!("adgjmps";"behknqt";"cfilor")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the reshape functionality of the take operator `#`. It takes two arguments: a LHS of at least 2 dimensions and the list to reshape.

For example `(3;4)#til 12` will reshape the list `0 1 ... 12` into a 3 by 4 matrix

In our case, the number of the number of elements in `l1` will will not necessary divide exactly into the number of elements in `l2` (we don't want a rectangular matrix). Instead we can supply a null as the second dimension which will take care of distributing the remainders.

```
q) l1!(count[l1];0N)#l2
a| 0 1 2 3 4 5
b| 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
c| 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

This method performs very well for larger input lists.

As a side note, when using `.Q.fc` to split a vector argument over `n` slaves for multi-threading, kdb uses the `#` operator to reshape the vector into `n` vectors, one for each slave.

Answer (score 0):

```
q)d:`a`b`c!{a where x = (a:til 20) mod y}'[til 3;3]
q)d
a| 0 3 6 9 12 15 18
b| 1 4 7 10 13 16 19
c| 2 5 8 11 14 17
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it